# Xamarin: NSException not handled even if caught

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an interesting problem, I'm catching an exception (and I hit the "catch" breakpoint when debugging) yet my app crashes because of an unhandled exception in the following code:

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            response = await this.MyHttpClient.GetAsync( _url );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

Stacktrace:

```
[0:] System.Net.WebException: The Internet connection appears to be offline. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Exception of type 'Foundation.NSErrorException' was thrown.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <54e129cad3ee4c61a6b46c3680ddc69a>:0 
  at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002f8] in <a827d263b32642a294603e46fea01afb>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <54e129cad3ee4c61a6b46c3680ddc69a>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.8.0.175/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <54e129cad3ee4c61a6b46c3680ddc69a>:0
```

Missing from the stackstrace is 1 line, which refers to the class/line which contains "response = await this.MyHttpClient.GetAsync( _url );"

How is this possible? NSErrorException inherits from Exception and thus should be caught - Which is is, since if I put a breakpoint in the catch block, the breakpoint is hit. What is going on? I'm very confused.

EDIT: By catching the exception on the platform (iOS) instead of in PCL i managed to get this not-very-useful stacktrace:

```
An unhandled exception occured.

2017-05-01 21:07:47.940 MyAppiOS[319:30171] 
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
2017-05-01 21:07:47.940 MyAppiOS[319:30171] Unhandled managed exception:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException)
(null)
2017-05-01 21:07:47.941 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical: Stacktrace:

2017-05-01 21:07:47.941 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical: 
Native stacktrace:
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:   0   MyAppiOS                            0x00000001000cd15c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 256
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:   1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000018f539348 _sigtramp + 52
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:   2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018f53f450 pthread_kill + 112
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:   3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000018f3eb400 abort + 140
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:   4   MyAppiOS                            0x00000001002012c0 xamarin_printf + 0
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:   5   MyAppiOS                            0x0000000100111814 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 132
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:   6   MyAppiOS                            0x00000001000ccc60 mono_handle_exception_internal + 3784
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:   7   MyAppiOS                            0x00000001000cbd8c mono_handle_exception + 40
2017-05-01 21:07:48.138 MyAppiOS[319:30171] critical:
Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client IDB44034 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.4.0.34/stop-app
```

EDIT2: Ignore the web exception, it was a distraction and an incorrect assumption by me (mistook the printed exception as the actual stacktrace, but it was not - it was only printed). Only the second stacktrace is relevant.
However, i did resolve the problem! Kind of. If i run my app using Xamarin Studio on a Mac, there is no issue. It is only when i run my app using Visual Studio and a build host that the problem persists. Both are running the same, up-to-date, xamarin and mac os. Very strange... I did manage to find this reported bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17419 but was unable to have success using the suggested solution. I just run my app on mac now.

Comment: It says your internet connection isn't available? Are you able to browse anywhere from your Safari browser on the Simulator/device? The second exception states  `NullReferenceException`. Are you sure all objects are initialized? Is your `MyHttpClient` instantiated?

Comment: I have added an edit - we should ignore the web exception. MyHttpClient *is* initialized, i checked. The NullReferenceException happens somewhere else, but ONLY when using Visual Studio + Build Agent, and apparently not in the app-code.